Magento PWA vs Scandi PWA vs Vue Storefront
I want to use the PWA on magento 2 for creating custom work.
Please suggest me which is best which one I should use and also tell me about the
resources where I can take help.

I have worked on scandi. It easy to develop and customize but now scandi community is not as much active as they were before. Perhaps they are busy in developing something new.
You can go for scandi if you are prepare and willing to handle everything at your own. I mean you need to fix if you encounter any issue, assume you will get no help from community.
You will be needing to take care specially about performance and seo part.
You will have two option if you are going with it.
Either use it as magento theme or use it as headless app.
ScandiPwa has documentation for developers, they are useful only for getting started and understanding there framework.Sometimes I found it less organized and confusing, not sure if that's only me finding it so.
I also have worked on vue storefront but I cant suggest you much about it. Currently they are on end of life of vue2 and migrating to vue3 and nuxt3.
I explored magento storefront years before at that time I found it little complex. Don't know how they are doing now but I see there git they have last commit a week before. Means they are maintaining there codebase.

Thank you so much for your information .Actually I am the only one responsible. I want to install on the local first do some kind of customization and then go for the next. I am new to the PWA.  Please suggest more with the resources which I can use for the working
